# Spectrum of $H = - \Delta + y^2 + a e^{b(x+y)}$.

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, partial-differential-equations, spectral-theory, quantum-mechanics

Define the Hamiltonian
$$
H = - \Delta + y^2 + a e^{b(x+y)}\,,
$$
where $- \Delta = - \partial_x^2 - \partial_y^2$ and $a,b > 0$. I'm trying to determine the spectrum and/or generalized eigenfunctions of this operator. I guess there is some scattering theoretic methods to achieve this but I'm not very familiar with the literature. Especially the problem seems to be that the potential $V(x,y) = y^2 + a e^{b(x+y)}$ does not decay, which is often assumed in scattering theory books.

---

Here is some of my work.

First consider the case where we forget the exponential term:
$$
H_0 = - \Delta + y^2\,.
$$
The eigenvalue equation $H_0 f = E f$ is separable and we get the eigenfunctions
$$
f_{p,n}(x,y) = g_p(x)h_n(y)\,, \quad p \in \mathbb{R}\,, \quad n \in \mathbb{N}\,.
$$
where 
$g_p(x) = C_1 e^{ipx} + C_2 e^{-ipx}$ and $h_n$ are the eigenfunctions of the quantum harmonic oscillator Hamiltonian. The function $f_{p,n}$ corresponds to the eigenvalue $E(p,n) = p^2+n$ which leads us to believe that the spectrum of $H_0$ is $[0,\infty)$ and since $f_{p,n}$ are not in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$ the spectrum should be fully continuous.

When we take into account the exponential term we expect that the solution  of $Hf = Ef$ has the asymptotics
\begin{align}
f_{p,n}(x,y) &\to 0 \text{ as } x \to \infty\,,\\
f_{p,n}(x,y) & \sim \left( e^{ipx} + R(y,p) e^{-ipx} \right) h_n(y) \text{ as } x \to - \infty
\end{align}
where $R(y,p)$ is the reflection coefficient of the 1-dimensional scattering problem with potential $x \mapsto ae^{by}e^{bx}$ and now $p \geq 0$.

This leads me to believe that the spectrum of $H$ is $[0,\infty)$, fully continuous and I can "label" the (generalized) eigenfunctions with $\mathbb{R}_+ \times \mathbb{N}$. I'd like to know if this is true, and if it is, how to do this more rigorously.

Comment: Consider an infinite potential well bounded by $y= \pi, -\pi$ and $x=0, \infty$. I think this has the essential features of your potential - it looks like a semi-infinite valley.

Comment: @KeithMcClary Yes, the spectrum is similar in this simpler case. But there is still the difference that in my problem I can't solve the equation $Hf = Ef$ explicitly.